# Cant disable Button using jquery in Django

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, django

I have i simple jquery function to disable a Button if the selected dropdown value is blank. But it wont work and i'm not sure why?

Here's my HTML:

```
<form action="{% url 'select_controller' id=i.ID  %}" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
<td>
    <select class="form-control"  name="controller" id="select_controller">
    {% if i.proposal_status == "Changes needed" %}
        <option value={{ i.ID_fk }}>  {{ i.ID_fk.last_name }}, {{ i.ID_fk.first_name }}</option>
    {% else %}
        <option value='blank'>  -</option>
        {% for controller in list_controller %}
            <option value={{ controller }}>  {{ controller.last_name }}, {{ controller.first_name }}</option>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}

    </select>
</td>
<td>
    {% if count_controller < 2 %}
        <button id="button"  class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Submit" > Send </button>
    {% else %}
        Only two regs
    {% endif %}
</td>
</form>
```

And this is my jQuery:

```
$("select").on('change',function(){
   if($(this).find('option:selected').text()=="-")
      $("#button").attr('disabled',true)
   else
      $("#button").attr('disabled',false)
});
```

I'm new to Javascript/jQuery but i think there is only one little thing i forgot

Comment: Are you sure that the jquery is triggered? (e.g. try to add an alert(); to your jquery)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you comparing the text of selected option, just compare its value, this'll be much simpler.

```
 $("select").on('change',function(){
   if($(this).val()=="blank")
      $("#button").attr('disabled',true)
   else
      $("#button").attr('disabled',false)
});
```

But Please make sure that you have disabled `button` on page `load`.

There is two way to do this working. First, you can disable `button` on page `load` in jquery. Second, on page `load` get the value of `select` and check that if it's value is `blank` then disable the `button`.

Comment: Are you sure jQuery is triggered?

Comment: I have other jQuery and javascript functions on the same html and they work

Comment: try this for once - `$("select").on('change',function(){
   alert($(this).val());
   });
`

Comment: okay this works, it gives me the selected value if i change it. I tried your first code once again and it work but only if i change the value and change it back to "-". But when i open the html it is auto set to "-" and the button is still  enabled

Comment: There is two way to do this working. First, you can disable `button` on page `load` in jquery. Second, on page `load` get the value of `select` and check that if it's value is `blank` then disable the `button`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112285/discussion-between-poonam-and-kynie).

Comment: Awesome thanks! I just disabled the button on create in the for loop and use the function you first posted. Can you put your last comment in a answer so i can mark this as solved?

Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Your options text content is actually `-`, notice the two spaces infront of the dash. The jQuery is reading those spaces and not counting `-` the same as `-`. Remove those preceding spaces and it should now work.

```js
$("select").on('change', function() {
  if ($(this).find('option:selected').text() == "-")
    $("#button").attr('disabled', true)
  else
    $("#button").attr('disabled', false)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="{% url 'select_controller' id=i.ID  %}" method="post">
  <td>
    <select class="form-control" name="controller" id="select_controller">
      <option value="test">test</option>
      <option value='blank'>-</option>
      <option value="testing">testing</option>
    </select>
  </td>
  <td>
    <button id="button" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Submit">Send</button>
  </td>
</form>
```

Comment: thanks for this quick reply. But sadly this is still not working i already tried this

Comment: It seems to be working in my example. Do you have a live demo somewhere that I could check out?

Comment: I don't have i live demo sorry

Answer (score 0):

We may also use:

`$('#button').prop('disabled',true);`

Some explanation on `.prop()` versus `.attr()` usage [here](https://api.jquery.com/prop/).